# Functions may be declared only at top level in strict mode

Tags: javascript

I have this error when using FireFox with strict mode. But am unsure what it means. I assumed it meant that the function had to be declared before it was called upon but the error still occurs.

> SyntaxError: in strict mode code, functions may be declared only at top level or immediately within another function

This is my snippet of code where it is causing the error:

```
var process = new function(){

  var self = this;

  self.test = function(value,callback){
    var startTime = Date.now();

     function update(){     //<--- error is here
                value++;
                startTime        = Date.now();

                if(value < 100){ 
                    setTimeout(update, 0);
                }
                callback(value);
    }       
    update();
  }

};
```

So i'm wondering how would I write this snippet of code out correctly with strict ? What does it mean by top level ? Does that mean globally defined and not locally within a function ?

Also given I have `use strict` why does this problem not occur in Chrome?

Comment: The error is `SyntaxError: in strict mode code, functions may be declared only at top level or immediately within another function`

Comment: `value++startTime = Date.now();`?

Comment: oops, yeh must of removed it when formatting the question

Comment: that snippet of code does not cause any error. Can you post a minimal example of code that demonstrates the issue you are experiencing

Comment: @JaromandaX probably because you did not turn on strict mode in Firefox.

Comment: @Dave - you'd be wrong - but, for kicks, where does one "turn on strict mode" in firefox

Comment: @JaromandaX well not sure then. For me it errors (but equally it doesn't error on Chrome using strict) So i don't know for sure whats going on lol

Comment: @BobfCali the link you provided, gives an answer that simply says to not use strict - which is not an answer.

Comment: @Dave - what does `turn on strict mode in Firefox` require me to do?

Comment: @JaromandaX very first line of your code before any thing requires `"use strict";`

Comment: @Dave - I understand how "use strict" works, I was wondering how to `turn on strict mode` **in Firefox** - as you have made that distiction

Comment: putting "use strict"; at the top of a file with your code in it generates **ZERO** errors in firefox

Comment: For you perhaps. But as the answer provided shows it was due to the order in which i had placed my function. I'm not sure why yours does not give an error.

Comment: You should include relevant versions when posting a question like this. I bet this was a bug in the version of Firefox you were using.

Comment: @JMM no it wasn't anything to do with version. And this question was from almost half a year ago. The answer has already been provided below.

Comment: @Dave how do you know it wasn't anything to do with version? I don't know what else would explain that answer making a difference.

Comment: Because the answer that i ticked as the correct answer solved the problem ? If you just scroll down the answer is right there next to a green tick, not sure why you don't understand this?

Comment: @Dave I don't see how it can be explained any more simply than I already did: "I bet this was a bug in the version of Firefox you were using." Although I have to admit that since posting that I've come to suspect that instead it may just be user error since the only information about the original problem state and indication that the answer resolved it are your reports.

Comment: Its not that difficult and its not a user error. Firefox handles strict different to chrome, thus i had to ask how i should be writing my code so both are happy. Firefox doesn't agree with the syntax but Chrome does. This goes back many versions of the browsers. Thus not a version issue either. The below answer fixes the problem for both browsers when using strict.

Comment: To be fair though i ditched using strict entirely due to the inconsistency, it was never worth the hassle.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You must put local functions BEFORE other code within the parent function in strict mode:

```
var process = function () {
    var self = this;
    self.test = function (value, callback) {

        function update() {
            value++;
            startTime = Date.now();
            if (value < 100) {
                setTimeout(update, 0);
            }
            callback(value);
        }

        var startTime = Date.now();
        update();
    }
};
```

This is described in this articles:

[New ES5 strict mode requirement: function statements not at top level of a program or function are prohibited](http://whereswalden.com/2011/01/24/new-es5-strict-mode-requirement-function-statements-not-at-top-level-of-a-program-or-function-are-prohibited/)

[MDN Strict Mode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Strict_mode)

In my own testing though (and counter to the articles I've read), I find that current versions of both Chrome and Firefox only complain about a local function definition if it is inside a block (like inside an `if` or `for` statement or a similar block.

I guess I need to go find an actual spec to see what is says.

Comment: Given I do not get this issue in Chrome, does that suggest `use strict` doesn't actually work in Chrome?

Comment: @Dave - Current versions of Chrome and Firefox seem to only complain about this issue when the function is located inside a block (like inside an `if` statement) though that is not how the feature is described in the sources I've read.

Comment: Hmm for me Chrome hasn't given me a single complaint yet. But FireFox hates everything lol. Seems Chrome is not so strict =/

Comment: Hmm, I don't believe this answer is correct in terms of the spec. The "immediately" in the warning should refer to nesting, not sequence. If changing the sequence of those statements really resolved the error, that sounds like a bug in Firefox. Also, note that ES5 and ES6 syntax differ with respect to this error. The error is for ES5, I don't believe it's applicable to ES6.

Comment: @JMM - It seems pretty clear that browsers and strict mode have changed their mind on this.  If you look at the 2nd code example [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Strict_mode#Paving_the_way_for_future_ECMAScript_versions), MDN clearly says something should cause a syntax error because of a nested function declaration that would not be allowed in strict mode, but all current browsers allow that.  Things seem a bit confused by this.  That's the info I wrote this answer from in 2015.

Comment: @JMM - And, my own testing at the time confirmed that a function defined within a block in strict mode caused an error (like the MDN example shows).  That is no longer the case as all three current browsers seem to allow that now.  Browsers are apparently a moving target in this regard. I would guess that ES6 changed the direction there.  We will have to investigate and find the actual spec language.  Does this really deserve a downvote for something that was entirely true at the time and has apparently changed since then?  I will attempt to update the question when new spec is found.

Comment: Downvote is because I don't believe it *was* entirely true at the time (except in some specific, unknown, bugged version of Firefox). Your answer is framed as if the spec says something about sequence of statements within a function (as opposed to nesting), but I don't think that was ever the case. Also, note that a) that's not what the MDN example says either and b) MDN is riddled with errors. ES6 did change the situation, but not in a way that relates to this question. This answer is mistaken with respect to ES5.

Comment: @JMM - I think this is the relevant portion of the ES6 spec: http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html#sec-block-level-function-declarations-web-legacy-compatibility-semantics, but I don't understand exactly what it means.  Clearly it is a mess largely because for years browsers chose their own set of extensions for functions declared within a block and thus not all chose the same.

Comment: Those are different issues. A function declaration was always allowed as a top-level statement *within another function*, right? It certainly appears that way in ES5 at any rate. And that's the case in the question code here. The only way `update` isn't "immediately within another function" is in terms of the sequence of top-level statements in the enclosing function's body.

Comment: you can do `var update = function() {};` instead (I'm pretty sure)

Answer (score 0):

The Internet explorer error explicitly states functions names cannot be "declared" within a function. So using a self-invoking function expression has worked for me.

This code fails:

```
    c.prototype.isitReal=function(t){
    var matched = false;
    this.each(function(item){
        // declaring a new function within a function fails 
        function getChildren(el){
            ....
            getChildren(el[a].children);
            ....
        }
        getChildren(el.children); // invoke function
    });
    return matched;
};
```

This code works:

```
    c.prototype.isitReal=function(t){
    var matched = false;
    this.each(function(item){
        // convert the function to an expression of a function
        // by wraping the entire function in ( )

        (function getChildren(el){
            ....
            getChildren(el[a].children);
            ....
            // then invoke the function expresion by adding ()
            // to the end. Pass in any arguments here also
        })(el.children,arg2,arg3);
    });
    return matched;
};
```

Tested in FF 76, MSIE 10, Chrome Canary 81