# Why TS complains with function declarations inside function body

Tags: javascript, typescript, ecmascript-5, typescript2.2

I have this error from TS:

[image]

It's pretty clear why the error occurs:

```
function outer(){

   if (true) {
        function inner(){    // nested function declaration

       }
   }   
}
```

but my question is - why does TS complain about that - is there some technical reason I should avoid nested function declarations when transpiling to ES5?

Would a function expression be a better choice, and why?

Comment: Possible Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10069204/function-declarations-inside-if-else-statements

Comment: Some useful links also here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33359840/functions-may-be-declared-only-at-top-level-in-strict-mode

Answer (score 8):

> Would a function expression be a better choice

Yes. The following is the way to go:

```
function outer() {
  if (true) {
    const inner = function() { // OK
    }
  }
}
```

> Why?

- ES modules are in strict mode by default.
- strict mode does not allow function declarations in blocks

Reason why it was disallowed is covered in the [original JavaScript specification](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/Ecma-262.pdf). Short version: *The behaviour was inconsistent between implementations*.

> NOTE Several widely used implementations of ECMAScript are known to support the use of FunctionDeclaration as a Statement. However there are significant and irreconcilable variations among the implementations in the semantics applied to such FunctionDeclarations. Because of these irreconcilable differences, the use of a FunctionDeclaration as a Statement results in code that is not reliably portable among implementations. It is recommended that ECMAScript implementations either disallow this usage of FunctionDeclaration or issue a warning when such a usage is encountered. Future editions of ECMAScript may define alternative portable means for declaring functions in a Statement context.

So when strict mode came into being (ES5) it made it disallowed.