# Is it a good idea to always set --alwaysStrict to true in tsconfig.json?

Tags: typescript, typescript2.0

Just curious whether there are any drawbacks to including:

```
"compilerOptions": {
  "alwaysStrict": true,
 ...
 }
```

Since it's false by default.  Thoughts?

Comment: It will `"Parse in strict mode and emit "use strict" for each source file"`, so your question is basically not different than: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1335851/what-does-use-strict-do-in-javascript-and-what-is-the-reasoning-behind-it

Answer (score 21):

### strict vs alwaysStrict

It is a good idea to **not only** include `alwaysStrict`, but to **include the `strict` flag** that enables `alwaysStrict` **and** also `noImplicitAny`, `noImplicitThis`,  `strictBindCallApply`, `strictNullChecks`, `strictFunctionTypes`, `strictPropertyInitialization` and `useUnknownInCatchVariables` which are even more important.

### Confusing names

There is a confusion about names here, because "strict" can mean few things here.
The `strict` TypeScript flag is a shortcut to enable multiple other flags mentioned above. The `alwaysStrict` TypeScript flag parses your files in parses in [the JS strict mode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Strict_mode) (as opposed to [the JS sloppy mode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Sloppy_mode) and emits `'use strict'` in the output. Instead of using the `alwaysStrict` flag you could add `"use strict";` to all of your files (the [ES modules](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/export) are strict by default).

### Other strict flags

The other strict TypeScript flags are even more important, because they help you eliminate these errors:

[image]

The `strictNullChecks` is the most important one in this respect.

It is not enabled by default for backwards compatibility with old code that was written before the new way of checking null and undefined was added.

See this answer for more details:

- [strictNullChecks and null value propagation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57178216/strictnullchecks-and-null-value-propagation/58868308#58868308)

Comment: This answer is outdated: as of TypeScript 4.3 in August 2021, the --strict flag enables all of these flags. See https://mariusschulz.com/blog/the-strict-compiler-option-in-typescript#strict-type-checking-options

Answer (score 9):

> Just curious whether there are any drawbacks to including

Even if your file is not going to be in `strict` mode, it will be treated like it is. e.g. you will not be allowed to create a function declaration inside a function body : [Why TS complains with function declarations inside function body](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43484701/why-ts-complains-with-function-declarations-inside-function-body/43487095#43487095)

Personally: Its a good idea to have it on. And an even better idea to always use JavaScript / TypeScript *modules* (which are in strict mode by default).