# strictNullChecks and null value propagation

Tags: typescript

I would like to start using `strictNullChecks` flag in a very big code base. It is definitely a very useful flag but I'm starting to include null types in most of the interface definitions. Maybe it's a personal perception since I never used the flag before, but it's starting to decrease the code readability (imho). I have the sensation that null is everywhere. All originates in a function returning `<type> | null` that propagates up in the functions call stack, forcing me to also include null types in interfaces.

Most of the time I have optional nullable fields like:

```
interface X {
  field?: string | null
}
```

This kind of things are a bit weird when both null and undefined are falsy values.

I've thought about replacing null types with undefined, eg: `<type> | undefined` to remove null types from optional interface fields so I just have:

```
interface X {
  field?: string
}
```

But then I lose the semantic value of null which is something that I would like to maintain.

So, what do you think about strictNullChecks? Do you find this kind of fields `field?: string | null` a bit weird or is something that you like and feel comfortable with it?

Comment: I personally use `undefined` instead of `null`. I keep `null` values for 2 cases only: 1/ on the backend, to represent a SQL `NULL` value, 2/ on the frontend, to deal with Vue.js observable objects (due to a limitation of Vue.js).

Comment: As a person with F# background where discriminated union types and `Option<T>` are a thing I think that having `string | null` in your code and not a quite big deal and the ability to know explicitly whether your type is nullable is a great benefit. So if you ask me: go ahead with it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Personally, I would suggest dropping `null` entirely, and using `undefined` instead.

If you have a semantic difference between a `null` and `undefined` value in your application, it's likely to cause confusion (in both TS & plain JS). If you don't, and you're just returning `null`/`undefined` at random, it'll be simpler and more consistent to use only one.

In terms of which to use, I suggest `undefined` primarily because TypeScript has slightly better support for it (i.e. `?`). There are arguments for using only `null` instead, it's just more verbose, and it's often convenient to have `undefined` as your indicator of missing data because it's the default value of every uninitialized variable/field, and those *should* usually have the same semantics & behaviour as explicitly unavailable data.

Answer (score 0):

I would agree with the answer by Tim Perry with regards to using only one - either null or undefined - and my advice is also to stick with undefined, mostly because you cannot avoid it as this is the value of missing fields and uninitialized variables.

Also null doesn't work for default function parameters:

```js
function f(x = 1) {
  // ...
}
```

Here `f(undefined)` will set `x` to `1` but `f(null)` will not!

The only argument for null is that JSON doesn't support explicit undefined but this is not such a problem as for those cases when you deserialize JSON that needs explicit null values (as opposed to just missing values, effectively meaning undefined) you can easily convert that.

In my projects I go as far as to forbid nulls with a linter config, e.g. for TSLint:

```
    "no-any": true,
    "no-null-keyword": true
```

This witch `strictNullChecks` works great in avoiding many kinds of errors.

Remember that the creator of NULL has called it his billion-dollar mistake. Having two nullish values is even worse. But if you have just one (like undefined) **and** you are using strict null checks in TypeScript then you can be pretty safe from the problems usually caused by null/undefined in most of the languages.

No matter if you go for undefined, null or both, I strongly advice you to always use strictNullChecks because without it your code is not really type safe.

See the [TypeScript 2.0 release notes](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-0.html) about null- and undefined-aware types:

> The type checker previously considered null and undefined assignable to anything. Effectively, null and undefined were valid values of every type and it wasn’t possible to specifically exclude them **(and therefore not possible to detect erroneous use of them)**. [emphasis added]

It is not enabled by default for backwards compatibility with old code that was written before the new way of checking null and undefined was added.

Consider this simple function:

```
const f = (x: string) => x.toLowerCase();
```

It is **not** type safe without the strict flags.
It can **crash** with runtime TypeError exceptions like:

> `TypeError: Cannot read property 'toLowerCase' of undefined`

With the strict flags:

```
const f = (x: string | null) => x.toLowerCase(); // COMPILE TIME ERROR
const f = (x: string | null) => x && x.toLowerCase(); // OK and safe
```

For more info, see:

- [Call me irresponsible if I crash on null or undefined in JavaScript or TypeScript](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PtGP6v29SZQ) (my talk on YouTube)
- [My arguments about enabling strict flag by default in Deno](https://github.com/denoland/deno/issues/3324#issuecomment-553453386)
- [More arguments for enabling all strict flags](https://github.com/denoland/deno/issues/504#issuecomment-552963725)

**Update:** Soon you will be able to use optional chaining in the example above:

```
const f = (x: string | null) => x?.toLowerCase(); // OK and safe
```

and even like this, if `x` could be not null but possibly a type without `.toLowerCase()` method:

```
const f = (x: string | number | null) => x?.toLowerCase?.(); // safe as well
```

For more info, see the documentation about the [optional chaining](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-7.html#optional-chaining) operator.