# how to pass callback data to koa ctx.body?

Tags: javascript, node.js, koa, ctx

I'm using Typescript with nodejs.I have `callback function` and i'm getting data as a object in body when i console. I want to pass data in data key of `ctx.body`. Can i push that `object` in other `variable` and then pass to `ctx.body`?

```
router.post('/api/send_otp', async (ctx: Koa.Context, next: () => Promise<any>) => {
        var phone = ctx.request.body.phone;

        if (!phone) {
            ctx.body = {
                message: "Please enter phone number",
            };
        } else {

    var options = {
        url: '',
        method: 'POST',
        auth: {
            'user': '',
            'pass': ''
        },
    };

    const callback = function(error, response, body) {
        if (response) {
            console.log(body); // Getting data here
        }else{
            console.log('error',error);
        }
    };

    request(options,callback);

    ctx.body = {
        data: body,   //I want data here
    }
});
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Comment: @Lux I tried some solution but not working for me.

Comment: You need to convert `request` to a promise style function. Then you can `await` it. (you should be inside an `async` function when you're using koa. For older koa versions `yield` it)

Comment: @Lux Can your edit my question? So i can understand easily how to do it.

Comment: could you post the wrapping `koa` code?

Comment: @Lux check now i've posted it.

Answer (score 0):

You can convert your callback style to promise and do it like this

```
const options = {
  "url": "",
  "method": "POST",
  "auth": {
    "user": "",
    "pass": ""
  }
};

function makeCall() {
  return Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    request(options, (error, response, body) => {
      if (response) {
        resolve(body);
      } else {
        reject(error);
      }
    });
  });
}

makeCall
  .then(body => {
    ctx.body = {
      "data": body   // I want data here
    };
  });
```

Please note that request is not maintained any more so better to use some modern packages like `got` and `axios`.

Comment: Error: Function declaration are not allowed inside blocks in strict mode

Comment: On function makeCall.

Comment: @MawWii see this link - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33359840/functions-may-be-declared-only-at-top-level-in-strict-mode

This is bec of `use strict` at the top of your file.

Comment: I am assuming you are having this function outside of your handler?

Comment: I'm not using `use strict` but my file is typescript

Comment: @MawWii you need to convert it to equivalent ts function

Comment: That's a real issue.